# How to switch dockpanels on binded object is null and not null, UpdateSourceTrigger not working i guess

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datacontext, tabitem

I have a view model bound to my TabItem DataContext. And it shows all the UIContols contained in that dockpanel (Lets say dockpanel's name is DoockpanelWithdata). 
What i want to do is, when i have the value of the Viewmodel object equals to null then i want to show other Dockpanel saying there is no data(Lets say DoockpanelWithOutData).

My try is this:

How to switch these dockpanels when VM==null and not null ?

```
 <TabControl>
            <TabItem Name="Tab1" Cursor="Hand">                   
                <ListView Name="lZ" ItemsSource="{Binding UObj}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem ,Mode=TwoWay}"  >//On selected item i bind the the tabitem below which show different dockpanels on GM=null and not null 
              //columns here
                </ListView>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Name="TabGraph"  DataContext="{Binding GM , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Cursor="Hand">                  
                <DockPanel Name="DoockpanelWithOutData">
                    <DockPanel.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="DockPanel">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GM, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DockPanel.Style>
                    <TextBlock>There IS NO DATA</TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel  Name="DoockpanelWithdata">
                    <DockPanel.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="DockPanel">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GraphVM, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DockPanel.Style>
                    //Some more data
                </DockPanel>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

In View Model(UR1R2_VM.cs) i have :

```
private ObservableCollection<UModel> uObj; //binded to itemsource of another TabItem
 public ObservableCollection<UModel> UObj
        {
            get { return uObj; }
            set { uObj= value; OnPropertyChanged("UObj"); }
        }
        private UModel selectedItem; //Binded to listView selecteditem  of another tabitem        
    public UModel SelectedItem //HERE INSTANCE IS CREATED
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            selectedItem = value;
            GM = selectedItem != null ? new GM(selectedItem.Nom) : null; //HERE INSTANCE IS CREATED
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");                
        }
    }     


    private GM gM;
    public GM GM
    {
        get { return gM; }
        set
        {
            gM = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GM");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code you have works fine for me, however are you making sure to set the DataContext of the content for `DockPanelWithData` though? Default DataContext will be your `UR1R2_VM`, and not your `Graph_VM` object. Other than that, can you put a breakpoint where you set GraphVM to make sure it's being set to the expected value?

Comment: I dont know if u have noticed that in my first tabitem i have binded listview selected item to Selecteditem property in my UR1R2_VM viewmodel . Which on selecting a row instantiates the GraphVM object. The second ab which contains both the dockpanel is set to datacontext of GraphVM class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go..

Just make sure that your `GraphVM` property is calling `RaisePropertyChanged` whenever it's changed (i.e., gets set to null). This is important in order for the trigger to get set.

```
<DockPanel Name="DoockpanelWithOutData">
  <DockPanel.Style>
    <Style TargetType="DockPanel">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DockPanel.Style>
  <TextBlock>There IS NO DATA</TextBlock>
</DockPanel>
<DockPanel  Name="DoockpanelWithdata">  
  <DockPanel.Style>
    <Style TargetType="DockPanel">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DockPanel.Style>   
  //Some more data
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: I feel like  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged is not working. It still  show DoockpanelWithOutData in both the case when GraphVM  is intialized and not intialized , in both the cases.

Comment: Either your DataContext is wrong, or your VM property is not set up correctly. Need more code? Post your relevant VM and VM property

Comment: Please see the listview where i do bindiing of SelectedItem , Because i instantiate  GraphVM on selecteditem of lsitview.

Comment: I see the issue. The DataContext is set wrong.. since the DockPanel is inside the TabControl, you need to trigger based on the outside DataContext. See update

Comment: I dont know if u have noticed that in my first tabitem i have binded listview selected item to Selecteditem property in my UR1R2_VM viewmodel . Which on selecting a row instantiates the GraphVM  object. The second ab which contains both the dockpanel is set to datacontext of GraphVM class.

Comment: Do uthink i may need relativesource  ?

Comment: OH THERE WAS SMALL PROBLEM; i SHOULD HAVE USED dataContext instead of GraphVM , please change  your answer so that i mark u as answer, u were very close to answer.